# How to convert PI controller in to differential equation?

Tags: control-theory, mathematics, transfer-function

I want to convert PI controller into Differential Equation form. How should I do this? Please help me.
[image: PI Controller]

[image: ODE from the book]

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried so far ? Split the block $k_p + K_i/s$ into two blocks and a summing junction. Then only a single item in the whole diagram will have anything to do with differential equations (and it is the simplest kind; all other equations are algebraic).

Comment: @AJN This is not a homework question. I am writing a ODE equation in MATLAB but my derivation is not matched with the given. That's why I asked here. I am attaching the solution.

Comment: Try splitting the block into two as mentioned above and **give a name to each (unique) signal line**. I think you will be able to find out where you made the mistake once you do both steps. Not marking the signal $u$ in the diagram has made it difficult to find the mistake.

Comment: From the comments, also to the answer, it's clear, you should provide more information to the reader. Nobody likes to suggest something, just to read "yeah, tried that, but ...". We simple aren't in your head :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the block diagram

```
x(t) --> [k/s] --> y(t)
```

It means (Laplace transform details from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems))
$$
y_{(t)} = k\ \int{x_{(\tau)}d\tau}
$$

Corresponding differential equation is
$$
\frac{d y(t)}{dt} = k\ x(t)
$$

Comment: Not matched with the solution that's why I asked here.

Comment: What is not matching with the solution? Do you have a  *wrong* solution and a  *right* solution with you? If so please post both in the question and label them. Please post the steps that led you to the wrong solution so that we can identify the error.

Comment: Then you need to _edit your question_.  This _is_ the correct solution mathematically; presumably you're having trouble implementing this in Matlab, so you should edit your question to say so, and to say what seems to be wrong.